# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, xml

when i try to luch my application, this error message appear, please help:

this is the error message:

```
   02-21 10:46:40.551    1092-1092/com.example.myapplication3.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication3.app, PID: 1092
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication3.app/com.example.myapplication3.app.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myapplication3.app.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the line of java code that is associated to this was an error is:
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.monBouton)).setOnClickListener(....)

this my code java:

```
package com.example.myapplication3.app;



public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.monBouton)).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                        EditText texte = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.monEditText));

                String nom = texte.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this, nom, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

code XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/monEditText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Taper votre nom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</EditText>
<!--
Le Bouton qui permettra à l’utilisateur
de valider sa saisie
-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/monBouton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Valider"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Given XML code is of layout fragment_main2.xml or activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `NullpointerException` because **your layout file does not contain a View (most likely a `FrameLayout`) with the id R.id.container**.

So this piece of code will crash:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
```

Because "R.id.container" does not exist in the layout file. Put a `FrameLayout` with the id "container" in your layout file. For example like that:

```
<FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: hi Philip Jahada, you mean like this:                       <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 <!--code xml here

Comment: Inside your layout file, you need a Framelayout that will contain the Fragment.

Comment: the FrameLayout already exists, I just mentioned that the problem occurs when I want to retrieve the event of a component!!

Comment: Stay calm, there is no need for multiple exclamation marks. Bear in mind that all people here are helping out voluntarily. In your onCreate() method, you are referencing R.id.container and R.id.monButton. One of those is not in the layout file that is loaded with setContentView() that is the reason for your crash.

Comment: I'm sorry if there was a miscommunication, thank you to everyone for their efforts

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.monBouton);
```

Then:

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Code here
                    }
 });
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion concerning readability of the code, but is not responsible for his NullPointerException.